# Payment gateway status set to pending magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento2, payment, order-status

I use `sample-module-payment-gateway` to test a payment gateway in magento 2, as i find out the order status is set to processing.

My question is how can i set this to pending, when a new order is placed?

I found a lot of tutorials about Magento-1. But not for Magento-2.

Answer (score 1):

ok after a few hours of searching magento 2, I found an answer for this question.

```
public function setStatus($orderId="") {
    $orderModel = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order'); 
    $order = $orderModel->load($orderId);
    $currentState = $order->getState();
    $currentStatus = $order->getStatus();

    $save = false;
    if ($currentState !== $orderModel::STATE_NEW) {
        $order->setState($orderModel::STATE_NEW);
        $save = true;
    }

    if ($currentStatus !== $orderModel::STATUS_FRAUD) {
        $order->setStatus($orderModel::STATUS_FRAUD);
        $save = true;
    }   

    if ($save) { $order->save(); }
}
```

This will set the payment sate to new and set the status to Pending.

can also use other status like

```
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';

const STATE_PROCESSING = 'processing';

const STATE_COMPLETE = 'complete';

const STATE_CLOSED = 'closed';

const STATE_CANCELED = 'canceled';

const STATE_HOLDED = 'holded';

const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW = 'payment_review';
```